# VCbuild not running with "accessing a corrupted shared library" under XP cygwin/x64

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit

I am trying to run vcbuild in XP 64 bit and visual studio 2008. The problem is rather puzzling, both because it makes little sense, and because I know very little of windows.
I am actually going to run it from cygwin, but it's not relevant I think. The error message in the title is the one I get on cygwin, and it spawned further research.

I am running windows 64 bit, installed VS2008 (with x64) and updated all the bunch.
When I open a terminal, and I try to invoke vcbuild, I get this

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio 9.0\VC\bin\amd64\vcbuild.exe"
The system cannot execute the specified program.
```

There's another vcbuild that runs

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsof
t Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\vcbuild.exe"
Microsoft (R) Visual C++ Project Builder - Command Line Version 9.00.21022
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

but as far as I understand it's 32 bit. I tried running dependency walker, and indeed it turns out that the first one is a 64 bit program (note the 64 bit icon), linking to 32 bit libs (???)

[image]

and the second one is a 32 bit program linking against 32 bit libs

[image]

I have no idea of what went wrong (or is wrong). I would say it is a variable definition problem. I tried calling vcvarsall.bat x64

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio 9.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat" x64
Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Beta2 x64 tools.
```

but no luck. Any idea ?

Comment: the reason it appears to be linked against 32-bit is because you are using the 32-bit version of Dependency Walker.  If you open it in the 64-bit version of Dependency Walker it should look normal.

Comment: @jcopenha: good point for the walker problem, but I still don't understand why vcbuild does not work. Even if a 64bit walker reports a linking against 64 bit libraries, why is it not running?

Comment: "Setting environment for using Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Beta2 x64 tools." -- perhaps the VS 2008 Beta2 build is not compatible with your current OS and patch level?